# Unbounded solution but bounded Euler discretization

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis, stability, discrete-dynamical-systems, discretization-and-quantization

Is there an ordinary differential equation in $\mathbb{R}^d$ induced by a gradient vector field with unbounded solutions, for which the difference equations obtained by using the forward Euler method have all solutions bounded?

---

I read the paper
*Guy, Richard T.; Misiurewicz, Michał*, Euler approximations can destroy unbounded solutions, Fasc. Math. 44, 43-52 (2010). [ZBL1215.65124](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1215.65124) (pdf also available [here](http://www.math.iupui.edu/%7Emmisiure/euler.pdf)). In this paper, the authors construct examples of differential equations with the form
$$\dot{x}=F(x)$$
that has an unbounded (in forward time) solution $x(t)$, but its Euler approximations for sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$
$$x_n=x_{n−1}+\epsilon F(x_{n−1})$$
have only bounded solutions. However, all examples they propose are not induced by a gradient vector field, i.e., we cannot write $F(x)=\nabla G(x)$ for some $G(x)$, where $\nabla$ stands for the gradient operator. It makes me think whether such phenomenon could happen even for a gradient vector field.

---

My guess is yes, but it seems hard to find an example that can be verified rigorously by analysis, not just by numerical experiments. Can anyone give a hint on it? It would be better if the example is a polynomial.

Comment: That’s really interesting.  By conservative system, it seems like you mean “gradient system”. Conservative system typically means that the dynamic conserves something like a first integral.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thanks for clarifying, I am confused with those two concepts, I have changed it to gradient system.

Comment: Here is a classical reference that clarifies these terms: https://books.google.com/books/about/Dynamical_Systems_and_Numerical_Analysis.html?id=ymoQA8s5pNIC.  See Chapter 2

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 2):

The central problem with forward Euler is that it doesn’t continuously update the vector field, and therefore can tunnel through fine features of the vector field.  The gradient case is no exception.  For concreteness, consider the 1D potential $$G(x) =(1/2) x^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \int_0^x \eta_{2^{-2-i}}(s - 1 + 2^{-i}) ds$$ where $\eta_{\delta}(\cdot)$ is a smooth nascent delta function with support in $(-\delta/2, \delta/2)$. Note that the supports of these nascent delta functions are disjoint. Starting say from $1/3$, the corresponding continuous solution is infinitely expansive in finite time and hence unbounded; whereas, for any step size $\epsilon>0$, the corresponding Euler solution will tunnel through an infinite # of nascent delta functions and hence remain bounded over a finite time window.

**Addendum**

In the comments, the OP shared a [potential  counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518700/long-term-behavior-of-a-nonlinear-dynamic-system), which was brought up in a recent MSE post on August 25th 2022 that remains unanswered. In this "counterexample", the underlying potential/loss/objective/cost function is: $$
G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2} x^2 y^2 - x - y \;.
$$  As noted in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518700/long-term-behavior-of-a-nonlinear-dynamic-system), based on numerical evidence, it looks like the forward Euler solution is bounded, but the exact solution seems unbounded.  These numerical observations can be validated (or refuted) using a standard stability analysis of the continuous/discrete dynamics outlined below.

First, note that the exact gradient dynamics has only one fixed point at $(1,1)$.  The eigenvalues of the Hessian evaluated at this fixed point $\nabla^2 G(1,1)$ are $3$ and $-1$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$, therefore the fixed point is [linearly unstable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_stability), and more precisely the instability is in the antidiagonal direction.

To determine the nonlinear stability of the fixed point in the anti diagonal direction, consider the [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function)
$$
\mathcal{V}(x,y) = (x-y)^2 \;,
$$
which measures the distance to the diagonal in the $xy$-plane.  A direct computation shows that
$$
\mathcal{L} V(x,y) = 2 x y \mathcal{V}(x,y) \;,
$$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the differential operator of the exact gradient dynamics.  This shows that the distance from the diagonal is non-decreasing if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, and in particular, increasing in a neighborhood of the fixed point $(1,1)$, until either  \begin{align*} 
&y = 1/x^2 \implies \dot{y}=0 ~~\text{and}~~  \dot{x}>0 ~~ \text{or} \\ 
& x=1/y^2 \implies \dot{x}=0 ~~ \text{and} ~~ \dot{y}>0 \;.
\end{align*}
In other words, the exact dynamics becomes (nonlinearly) unstable due to the gravity-like terms in $G(x,y)$, but this instability is weak (non-exponential).

On the other hand, the situation is a bit different along the forward Euler solution.    The fixed point is still unstable with eigenvalues of the linearized (discrete) dynamics being $1-3 \epsilon$ and $1+\epsilon$ with the same eigenvectors.  To assess the nonlinear stability in the anti diagonal direction, we use the same Lyapunov function $$
\mathcal{V}(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) = (1+\epsilon x_n y_n) \mathcal{V}(x_n, y_n) 
$$
Thus, the distance to the diagonal is increasing in the region
$$
\{ x, y : |1 + \epsilon x y | > 1 \}
$$
which includes the region where $ x y >0$ but also $x y < -2 /\epsilon$.  At a fixed step size, for small time interval the Euler solution essentially behaves like the exact solution, but for larger time intervals instead of asymptoting to one of the following trajectories \begin{align*} 
&y = 1/x^2 \implies \dot{y}=0 ~~\text{and}~~  \dot{x}>0 ~~ \text{or} \\ 
& x=1/y^2 \implies \dot{x}=0 ~~ \text{and} ~~ \dot{y}>0 \;,
\end{align*}
it can catastrophically lose stability and blow up because the component that is small can change sign and the dynamics in that component becomes unstable, and in turn, the dynamics in the other component grows without bound.

This is borne out numerically.  Here is a a trajectory of forward Euler at $\epsilon = 1/6$ in the $xy$-plane over the time interval $[0,10]$ initiated at $(1.6,1.5)$.  The size of the dots increase with time. At first, the Euler solution is essentially following the continuous dynamics and everything looks fine.  However, note that when the $y$-component becomes small, and because forward Euler does not continuously update the gradient, the $y$-component can change sign, which leads to an unexpected/dramatic/artificial instability.

[image]

Comment: Nice example, but it would be better if the function is more elementary, like a polynomial (maybe 2-d, because 1-d polynomial seems doesn't work).

Comment: It might be possible to construct a 2D polynomial example, but the failure might be less spectacular.  Importantly, the construction will follow the same principle: forward Euler can fail to "see" important features of the vector field if the step size is too big.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand your point. I would like an example so that forward Euler fail for all sufficiently small step size, i.e., I fix a function, and there exists $\alpha_0>0$ such that for any step size $\alpha\in(0,\alpha_0]$, forward Euler is bounded even if the continuous solution is unbounded (but the bound could depend on $\alpha$). Your example seems to say that I first choose any small step size and then find a corresponding function.

Comment: This example seems to satisfy that requirement, because for any $\epsilon>0$ forward Euler will only see a finite number of the nascent delta functions; whereas the true solution will see an infinite number of them.

Comment: How does $\epsilon$ depend on $\delta$? If for different $\epsilon$ we need different $\delta$, then the function $G(x)$ is actually changing right?

Comment: Yes, you are indeed correct.  Therefore, in order to ensure that Euler does not see more than a finite # of the nascent delta functions at any step size $\epsilon>0$, it suffices to slightly adjust the $G(x)$ given in the answer, such that the $\delta$ for each nascent delta function depends on the center of the nascent delta function: $\delta_i = 2^{-i}/4$.  This ensures, in particular, that the supports of the nascent delta functions are disjoint.

Comment: Here is another dramatic counterexample which is based on the same principle, but requires a restricted initial condition for the forward Euler solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1507138/examples-where-constant-step-size-gradient-descent-fails-everywhere?rq=1.  One can readily exploit this artifact (oscillatory behavior of the Euler solution) to construct a potential such that Euler remains bounded (for the restricted initial conditions) whereas the true solution (initiated at the same points) can become unbounded.

Comment: I think this function is coercive, so the true solution is bounded? I found an example with very simple formula, but I don't know how to prove the Euler is bounded. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518700/long-term-behavior-of-a-nonlinear-dynamic-system

Comment: It is certainly coercive, and to exploit the artifact where Euler gets stuck in a periodic loop, you just need to add a second component, and as a function of that second component, add a non-coercive term to the potential energy which turns on when the first component is small.  An addendum to the answer addresses the "counterexample" you brought up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!

Comment: You're welcome!  And thank you for the interesting question.

Comment: I think it's probably a good idea to link this question/answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4518700/long-term-behavior-of-a-nonlinear-dynamic-system  I don't have an account with MSE so I can't do it.  Could you please add a link?  Also, have your questions been resolved?

Comment: Good idea, but I am still working on writing a rigorous proof for boundedness of Euler solution. I took step size $\alpha=0.01$ and iteration number $N=10000$, and found the iterates form an ellipse. Thus, it is bounded, but I don't know how to prove.

Comment: Are you using the same initial condition?  If so, how can we be getting different results?

Comment: Why is it different? I think we obtain consistent result, that is, the Euler solution is bounded (not convergent), but the continuous solution is unbounded.

Comment: I’m sorry, I am very confused.  In the polynomial example you shared, the Euler solution is unbounded.  The numerical evidence is very clear on this point and the reason is detailed in the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Your numerical experiment is unbounded because you take too large step size for the initial point you choose. Since the gradient of $G(x)$ does not have a global Lipschitz constant, we need to select small enough step size for each different initial point (that is what I mean sufficiently small, not a single small step size for all initial point, but one step size for one initial point). I used your initial point, but reduced $\epsilon$ to be $\epsilon=0.01$, and run $10000$ iterations, I saw all iterates lie in a bounded region and some periodic pattern occurred.

Comment: In my experience, it is often tricky to prove anything about discretizations when they are far away from the continuous solutions they are aimed at.  This is one reason why we devote so much time to studying continuous system because that’s all we really know about.

Comment: I agree, it is hard to prove. However, it is still surprising to see in experiment that for such a simple function (bivariate 4th order polynomial), we have such a discrepancy between continuous and discrete solution.

Comment: BTW, even the paper you shared did not provide a time-independent polynomial example for conservative systems.  All three examples in the paper are actually very complex; even the third example is time-dependent.  So I'm not sure why it should be any easier in the gradient case.  Nonetheless, the example given in this example is 1D!  (Every autonomous 1D ODE is of gradient type.)

Comment: Indeed, your example is pretty nice. Just to ensure my understanding, the function $G(x)$ you purposed can be easily made $C^\infty$ but may not be analytic or semi-algebraic right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  I also think there are many other perhaps more generic examples in 1D for gradient systems, and they will be based on the same principle given in the answer above.